# Form mailer security

Tags: php, forms, email, security

I have a php based form mailer. I am using it for a long time already. However, I am wondering if it would be possible to make it more secure. Anybody who sees a vulnerability in the following code? Is there anything where a possible hacker could inject something? Other possible vulnerabilities that I could think of would be deprecated code that is considered unsecure and therefore is normally replaced by something else.

```
<?php
$straddressee = 'info@myexample.com';
$strFrom       = '"mailer" <dictformmail@myexample.com>';
$strSubject    = 'Message';
$strReturnhtml = 'thankyou.php';
$strDelimiter  = ":\t";

if($_POST)
{
 $strMailtext = "";
 while(list($strName,$value) = each($_POST))
 {
  if(is_array($value))
  {
   foreach($value as $value_array)
   {
    $strMailtext .= $strName.$strDelimiter.$value_array."\n";
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $strMailtext .= $strName.$strDelimiter.$value."\n";
  }
 }

 if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
 {
  $strMailtext = stripslashes($strMailtext);
 }

 mail($straddressee, $strSubject, $strMailtext, "From: ".$strFrom)
  or die("The email could not be sent.");
 header("Location: $strReturnhtml");
 exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
    <p>Your message:</p>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities("/mailer/"); ?>" method="post">

<p>Salutation:<input type="text" name="Salutation" /></p>
<p>Your Name:<input type="text" name="name" /></p>
<p>Your Email:<input type="text" name="email"  size="30"></p>
<p>Subject:<input type="text" name="subject"  size="35"></p>
<p>Your message:<textarea name="Message">message</textarea></p>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Someone could automate the form submissions and flood your mailbox with emails. In other words: There no brake on how often, and with what input, the form can be submitted. Whether this is actually a problem for you is another matter. The chance of someone actually trying this is not so big.

Comment: How can I prevent automation?

Comment: A basic method is the so-called ['honeypot'](https://dev.to/felipperegazio/how-to-create-a-simple-honeypot-to-protect-your-web-forms-from-spammers--25n8). It's a field users won't fill out, but a spambot might.

Comment: You could add a captcha. You should also add some protection against [CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) (might not be needed if you have captcha). Without any of those (or something equal), someone can just bypass your form altogether and post directly to the above PHP.

Comment: Apart from getting spammed yourself, I don't see any other security risks in your code.